# Getting JSON file from localhost using ServiceHandler and AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have added a `questions.json` file to www folder and I'm trying to retrieve it.
**problem is** the response always returns null I'm guessing the exception is at `httpClient.execute(httpGet);` , not sure though

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class QuestionListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment 
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // url to make request
        private static String url = "http://localhost/questions.json";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_QUESTIONS = "Questions";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "Question_Id";
        private static final String TAG_BODY = "QuestionBody";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "QuestionTitle";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "Asker_Name";
        private static final String TAG_TIME = "Created At";
        private static final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
        private static final String TAG_ANSWER = "answer";
        private static final String TAG_A_NAME = "Name";
        private static final String TAG_RATING = "Rating";


        // questions JSONArray
        JSONArray questions = null;
        ListView lv;
        Context c;
        JSONObject obj ;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(ask.code.R.layout.questions_list_frag, container, false);


         new GetQuestions().execute();

         return view;
    }

    private class GetQuestions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    questions = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);



                        // looping through All Questions
                        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                            String body = c.getString(TAG_BODY);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);


                            JSONObject answers = c.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
                            String answer = answers.getString(TAG_ANSWER);
                            String a_name = answers.getString(TAG_A_NAME);
                            String a_rating = answers.getString(TAG_RATING);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                            map.put(TAG_BODY, body);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            questionsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), 
                    questionsList, 
                    ask.code.R.layout.question_item,
                    new String[] {
                        TAG_NAME,
                        TAG_TITLE,
                        TAG_TIME},
                    new int[] {
                        ask.code.R.id.asker_name,
                        ask.code.R.id.question_title,
                        ask.code.R.id.question_rating});


            setListAdapter(adapter);



                }



    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  

    }






        // TODO Auto-generated method stub







}
```

**ServiceHandler**

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

**questions.json**

```
{
    "Questions": [
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2013-07-31T09: 57: 34.618Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Cloyd",
            "QuestionTitle": "temporadoloremquevoluptatemestquisquamundevoluptatemsuntearum\nsitfugaducimusnequeomnisin\npariaturminusdebitisquaeratrerumnamvelitveritatisrem",
            "QuestionBody": "voluptatemtemporadignissimosanimivelitdelectusconsequaturcumquedeserunt\nillumaperiamquisminimaeumremveniam\nutnumquamdoloremconsequaturvoluptatemofficiaveniam\nutarchitectoiddelenitiuteiuscumpossimus\ndolorumprovidentmollitianullarerum\n\r\tquiainarchitectodebitislaboreerror\nvoluptatibussitquaeratdoloreassumendadoloremdoloresconsectetur\nsedetevenietsaepeconsequaturvelarchitecto\n\r\tdolorumvoluptatemquaevoluptatebeatae\ndoloremqueutofficiisquibusdamiustopariaturiureautdolorem\nidquialiquideosvelet",
            "Question_Id": 0,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "1997-08-05T20: 13: 37.888Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Alexander",
            "QuestionTitle": "fugaetnequequoettemporibus\natvoluptatumessesit\nnullaadipisciquaeducimus",
            "QuestionBody": "quiainciduntetquoserror\ncumqueetautsitidexcepturiaccusantiumpariaturconsequatur\nlaudantiummaioressedillomagniexplicabo\nindolorprovidentvoluptasearumdelenitidelectusmollitia\n\r\tsapienteinnemo\nexpeditaautinnon\nprovidentabveniamut\n\r\tenimducimussuntrerumnamsed\nsaepepraesentiumaliquamverolaborumdeseruntidex\nautsedvelittemporibusexplicaboveniamvoluptatemin\nisteetutnobisprovidentasperiores\nexpeditaitaqueullam",
            "Question_Id": 1,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "1990-02-16T06: 37: 46.327Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Kade",
            "QuestionTitle": "nisidelectusasperioresveletidtempore\nrationeautautet\neaquenisiestrerumodioasperiorescupiditate",
            "QuestionBody": "exrepellendusliberoeosautemetdictaautemsed\nabconsequaturetsitvoluptatemassumendavelitsint\nautconsequaturveniamodioquodoloremdolorem\neligendirerumexplicaboquiquiadolorem\n\r\tminusvoluptatemnamvelcupiditateaperiamsedrerumearum\nautrepudiandaeeavelsitreprehenderiteterrorfugiat\nsedeaquidemveritatisiure\n\r\tdoloremqueidsuntatquiacorruptimolestiaeexpeditavoluptate\nnontemporevelitestrepellendus\nessequaeinsit\nporronihilfacereautnecessitatibusquosunt\natlaborumatemporaullam",
            "Question_Id": 2,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "1987-02-28T20: 39: 36.422Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Madaline",
            "QuestionTitle": "omnisnesciuntexcepturieligendirerumquam\netmolestiasfugiatremvoluptasvelitautet\nsedoccaecatidelectuseoset",
            "QuestionBody": "inciduntquosbeataevoluptasidcommodideseruntexvero\netitaquemollitialaborumnemosedvoluptatibusperferendisdoloremque\nestsuscipitnonveniamutquaeaperiam\nveroetquiaautillo\nasperioressimiliquetempora\n\r\tvoluptatemaccusantiumconsequunturetconsequaturrepellataut\naspernaturnesciunteavoluptasnatusmaxime\nmaioresatconsequaturnequereiciendis\nadipiscienimrationeipsummagnamveniamsed\n\r\treiciendisutundequi\naperiamcorporisnesciuntid\nculpaetreprehenderittemporibusofficiaplaceataccusantiumcum\nquassitmaioresdelectusesse\nconsequaturtotamdolor",
            "Question_Id": 3,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "1991-11-22T12: 50: 21.965Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Lizzie",
            "QuestionTitle": "quiaremnatus\nnatusofficiisquamomnisquifuga\nquiasitavoluptatem",
            "QuestionBody": "quisvoluptasquilaborumsednostrumfugaea\nipsumquaeratveritatis\nporrouterrorex\nauteiusexplicabononfugaadutvoluptatumnihil\nabnoninarchitectocommodiminusquasanimi\n\r\tenimdebitisbeataemollitiadoloresiureiustoquia\ncommodiquiapossimusatemporibus\nidutnobisvoluptatumfugaaccusamusharum\netdictaquiamollitiaaccusamuspossimusvoluptatibusautalias\nautemdoloremnamaliquam\n\r\tsitdeseruntautestexcepturiquasi\nquibusdamevenietexcepturiducimusquosdicta\nearumsitenimautquisquamaliquam\nmagnamnesciuntinciduntvelitarchitectoomnis\nomnisminimaerrorfuga",
            "Question_Id": 4,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "1987-05-09T15: 46: 08.048Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Colleen",
            "QuestionTitle": "rerumetaccusamussedabdolorenonest\nestperspiciatisquisedsintmolestiaeautcorporisomnis\nperferendisvelenim",
            "QuestionBody": "iustomolestiasrerummollitiafacilisatquecumque\neumquaeatqueaspernaturadoloresestomnis\ndolornihilexcepturinecessitatibus\n\r\tidveniamevenietquifugiat\nreprehenderiterrornumquamautetquiquiarerum\ndolorummaximequasicorporismodiin\neosnostrumutsapientedoloremque\nquaeratconsequunturveniamperferendisautnisidoloresnonest\n\r\tquisuscipitadconsequaturrepellatvoluptatemmollitia\nquidemverocum\nmodidelenitivoluptasadipisciodio",
            "Question_Id": 5,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2002-05-04T05: 31: 45.704Z",
            "Asker_Name": "Carlotta",
            "QuestionTitle": "impeditquodillumconsequunturlabore\nsitundeblanditiisitaqueiustoutcorporisut\ndeseruntquasquam",
            "QuestionBody": "illumevenietdolor\ndoloribusdistinctiorerumvoluptatumquibusdamest\ndoloremquevoluptassitautemeos\nexcepturiquieasuntverodictaatque\n\r\tisteullamut\nanimivoluptasautdoloresoccaecatiuttenetur\neaimpeditautaquispossimusperspiciatisestaccusantium\nutconsequaturminimabeataemolestiae\ndoloresdolorethic\n\r\tquisquamquidempariaturassumendalaborumveritatisquasdolore\ncommodiquaedebitisipsafugitcorporissitharumquam\nvoluptasbeataeeaetetutaperiam\naiurenihilnamnonaut\ndoloresprovidenthicetveroautmagnimaximelabore",
            "Question_Id": 6,
            "Answers": {
                "Answer": "temporakdjd",
                "Name": "saleem",
                "Rating": "10"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect to the server by specifying `localhost` as the address of the system hosting the service. The Android emulator runs inside a Virtual Machine (QEMU). Hence, `localhost` would be the **emulator's own loop back address, and not that of the system.**

So, you can either go to CommandPrompt in your Windows to get the IP address of your system or just use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/...` instead of using `localhost`.

**`private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/questions.json";`**

Answer (score 1):

if you are using emulator then you have to write 10.0.2.2 in place of localhost.
if you are using your device then you have to connect to same network and have to replace localhost with your computer ip address.

i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        //URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        URL urlObj = new URL(url.replace(" ","%20"));
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    }catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }


    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
public ServiceHandler() {

}
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


    try {
        //URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        URL urlObj = new URL(url.replace(" ","%20"));
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new       BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    }catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }


    return result.toString();
   }
   }
```

Comment: This looks like a copy of soumit's unexplained code dump below. Please post original answers that are in fact answers to the question.